# Callback on success: Should err be null or undefined

Tags: node.js

```
function myAsyncFn( params, callback ) {
    var result;

    /*
       something...
       ...with success!
    */
    callback( null, result ); // this?
    // callback( undefined, result ); or this?
}
```

I am wonderíng what is the expected value of `err` in a callback on success. Is it `null` or `undefined`?

Comment: I've seen both used before but ideally it shouldn't really matter as long as it's some false-y value. Most people just do `if (err) {}` in the callback.

Comment: `null` is assignable value so I think you should be using `null`

Comment: Any falsey value will work, but `null` is more commonly used than `undefined`, but it really doesn't matter which you use.

Comment: null is the general convention that is frequently used